# SQL : Summing only distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Below is the result of query. There are more columns and rows but for this question lets only consider these columns and rows.

| FEP_INR | FEP_FEE | FEP_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| 00015504 | DOSETFEEOV | 175 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 00015505 | DOSETFEEOV | 30 |
| 00015504 | DOSETFEEOV | 175 |
| 00015504 | DOSETFEEOV | 175 |
| 00015504 | DOSETFEEOV | 175 |

I want to further query this subset so that I get the `SUM` of the FEP_AMT only for the distinct combinations of FEP_INR (value not known) and FEP_ACCOUNT (value known).
I have tried
`CASE WHEN FEP_FEE = 'DOSETFEEOV' THEN SUM(FEP_AMT) OVER () END` and
`CASE WHEN FEP_FEE = 'DOSETFEEOV' THEN SUM(FEP_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY FEP_INR, FEP_FEE) END` but this sums all records where FEP_FEE = 'DOSETFEEOV' and that is not what I want.

In the end the sum should be 205 (30 + 175).

Hope someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select FEP_INR,FEP_FEE, sum(FEP_AMT) from
(
 select distinct FEP_INR,FEP_FEE, FEP_AMT 
 from table_name
 where FEP_AMT is not null
) as a group by FEP_INR,FEP_FEE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix your problem earlier in the query.  But based on your description:

```
select sum(fep_amt)
from (select distinct fep_inr, fep_fee, fep_amt
      from t
     ) t;
```